# What is the difference between bracketed and non-bracketed if-statements in bourne shell?

Tags: if-statement, sh

For instance:

```
if $input = 'y'
```

causes

> ./test.sh: line 5: y: command not found

While

```
if [ $tmp = 'y' ]
```

causes no error?

What is the purpose of an if statement that cannot evaluate conditions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if` doesn't evaluate anything. It simply executes the predicate program and acts on its return code. `[` is actually a program that does a handful of conditions, and returns an appropriate return code.

`[` can be used with oneliners without if, if you don't need the `else` branch:

```
$ [ 1 -eq 2 ] && echo "foo"
# -> no output
```

Comment: @cnicutar: that is correct. Modern shells also provide `[[` that is fully a builtin and has more features.

Comment: @anonymous: extends on the `[` that is quite old by now. Old bourne shell doesn't support it AFAIK. But for bash, you can learn about it here: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html#DBLBRACKETS